# I am unable to access a memory address given in a string

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory-address

So my problem is that i have to read the content of a file into the buffer (that is a void*).

I searched a lot and I can't find any information about converting the memory address in the string to an actually void*, and probably has a dumb solution but I have to ask here.

This my code:

```
int ReadFile(char *f, void *p, ssize_t cont)
{
    struct stat s;
    ssize_t n;
    int fd;

    if (stat(f, &s) == -1 || (fd = open(f, O_RDONLY)) == -1)
    {
        perror("ERROR: ");
        return -1;
    }
    if (cont == -1) 
        cont = s.st_size;
    if ((n = read(fd, p, cont)) == -1)
    {
        perror("ERROR: ");
        close(df);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Read %ld bytes from %s in %p\n", n, f, p);
    close(df);
    return 0;
}
```

I think this function is kinda ok.

My problem resides into when I call it, the program asks for an input, like a shell, this can be an example of request:

```
> read file.txt 0xffffffff 15
```

being 0xffffffff the memory addres where `read` will send the bytes gotten, my program gets this memory address as a string like:

```
"read file.txt 0xffffffff 15"
```

I already have the step where I split all this string into segments like: `"read"` , `"file.txt"` , `"0xffffffff"`, `"15"`.

But when I have to pass the function `read` the required arguments, I can't find the way to convert `"0xffffffff"`  to `0xfffffff`.

Comment: You need to convert the string to an integer, and then cast the integer value to a `void *`. But this is a pointless thing to do on a desktop computer, because it'll most likely result in a segmentation fault when you try to use the pointer.

Comment: What is the ulterior motive you have, for attempting to do this? This question read like a ["XY problem"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/157291) to me.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't find the way to convert "0xffffffff" to 0xfffffff.

```
unsigned val;
sscanf("0xffffffff", "0x%x", &val);  //you can also "%x"

// now val contains the value needed
```

Replace `"0xffffffff"` with your string.

Comment: Check the return value of `sscanf`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Chris, can I ask a question? What is the reasoning behind putting 0x before the %x in the format? I tried this solution and it worked but I couldn't understand at all this part. I looked in the man of sscanf to see if I could get something there but I didn't find anything.

Comment: 0x in the format matches the literal "0x" at the beginning of the string.